# Easiest way to hash set of integers?

Tags: c, hashtable

I have a set of ~2000 monotonic large integers (32-bit) which must serve as keys to a hash table. How can I take advantage of this constraint to efficiently hash them?

Comment: xor them all, for instance

Comment: If you are using a hash table with 2000 defined integer keys why couldn't the integers be indicies into the hash table (an array)?

Comment: If the keys are very large, it will use up a lot of memory.

Comment: What does monotonic have to do with it? Anyway I suggest the standard `modular hashing, where the hash function is simply h(k) = k mod m for some m` It is simple to implement and has worked well for me in the past.

Comment: Gone are the days when ~2000 is too large a size for an array to be.

Comment: Java solves this (java.lang.Integer.hashCode) by just returning the value. I suppose it would make sense to have a prime number of buckets and use `value % p`  to pick the bucket.

Comment: But if the key is 9423849223, I can't create an array index like that can I? Also, they are not equally spaced.

Comment: Unless you know something a priori about the distribution of the integers, you can't do significantly better than - as others have said - choosing a prime table size and using `table_index = (unsigned) val % (size_t) size`.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I take advantage of this constraint (monotonic) to efficiently hash them?

Given that the keys are sorted (monotonic) is unlikely to aid in any hashing as hashing, in general, attempts to defeat the ordering of keys.

Hashing chops up any key is a seemingly non-ordered fashion.

Not only are keys and related data needed to be added to a hash table, *access* (simply reads) to the hash table is done through keys which are certainly not sorted.

If original keys are sorted and access is sequential, then a hash table should not be used in the first place.